# How to get video play paused status with Vimeo API?

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo, vimeo-player

I was just wondering how I can detect if the video is playing or paused (or even loaded/ buffering) on the Vimeo API (http://player.vimeo.com/playground) it's a lot different to Youtube!

Joe

Answer (score 3):

Check the richest [example of using vimeo Player Javascript API](http://player.vimeo.com/playground). It uses froogaloop library to communicate vimeo JS API. Don't forget to add id and parameters to the iframe element.

```
  <iframe id="player_1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7100569?api=1&amp;player_id=player_1" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Vimeo Player JavaScript API provides the following method:

`paused():Boolean`

This return returns false if the video is playing, true otherwise.

Full details here: http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Comment: That page includes sample code for using the JS API. They support two approaches, one manual and one that uses their library. Both are well documented and in fact they include a live example of exactly what you are looking for - see screenshot here: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s143/sh/82cd1506-78b2-4ea5-9133-c7b62751bf4f/709f5d40dd2327c89c60f29ad02f0da6/deep/0/Screenshot%204/12/13%2010:33%20AM.jpg

Comment: Ah thanks! It's hard to see that's a full example- will investigate it now :)

Comment: That example shows how to use the pause EVENT, not the paused():Boolean method. I still can't figure it out either.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like their documenentation slightly changed since last answer. After you get the instance of the player you can check the playing/pause state by:

```
player.getPaused().then(function(paused) {
    if(paused){
        player.play();
    }else{
       player.pause();
    }

});
```

From vimeo [player api docs](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#getpaused-promiseboolean-error)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you have to pass a callback as a second param to `.api()`, which will receive `true` / `false` based as the pause state of the player:

```
player.api('paused', function(paused) {
    // paused will be true or false here
});
```

https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/issues/31

Comment: Note that if you have multiple players on the page, you'll also need to add a bit to the embed code. From the docs: "If you’re embedding and controlling multiple players on a page or using our JS API library (Froogaloop), you should give each player a player_id that matches the id of the iframe element.

http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?api=1&player_id=vimeoplayer

Answer (score 1):

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  const player = new Player(iframe);
  
  player.loadVideo(123456).then(() => {
    player.ready().then(() => {
      player.on('pause', (data) => console.log(data));
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var onPlay = function(data) {
              console.log("play")
            };

            var onPause = function(data) {
              console.log("pause")
            };

            player.addEvent('play', onPlay);
            player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
```